# display an image from mysql blob in modx

Tags: mysql, printing, blob, modx

There is a modx snippet for catalog (below). And there is a chank (template), in which i need to paste a piece of code to show an image, stored in mysql database for each block in the catalog list. The data call is [[+pic]], but simply putting it this way prints a sequence of (ascii ? ) symbols. There are suggestions on how to load and print an (blob) image from db, but it seems to me it can crash server by multiple calls to db for each block in the catalog for several users at once.

snippet:

```
<?php
$path = MODX_CORE_PATH . 'components/zzz/';
$result = $modx->addPackage('zzz', $path . 'model/','wep_');
if (! $result) {
  return 'bla-bla-bla';
}

$sortByDatetime = 'datetime';     //sortby date
$sortByName = 'company_name'; //sortby alphabet

$s = $modx->newQuery('Company');

$s->sortby($sortByDatetime,'ASC'); //first-order sorting
$s->sortby($sortByName,'ASC'); //sub-group sorting

$s->where(array(
   'type'     => $filter,
));
$out = $modx->getCollection('Company',$s);

$output = '';
$num = 0;
foreach ($out as $item) {  //get each $item from $out collection
    $fields = $item->toArray();
    $output .= $modx->getChunk('showAllCompaniesTpl', $fields);  //append parts by template
                $num += 1;
                if ($num == 10) break;
}
return $output;
```

So, how to show (decode?) image from blob for the set of entries into catalog in a few code lines if it is possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put this after `$fields = $item->toArray();` and try again

```
$fields['pic'] = '<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode($fields['pic']).'"/>';
```

if your images not `png` - change `image/png`